# Integer based rewrite isn't recognized for value of 1

Tags: url-rewriting, query-variable

I have a simple rewrite to pass a variable:

```
// Add custom URL parameters
function add_custom_query_var( $vars ){
  $vars[] = "item_id";
  return $vars;
}

add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_custom_query_var' );

// Add rewrite for custom query vars
function custom_rewrite_basic() 
{
    add_rewrite_rule('^add-item/([0-9]+)/?', 'add-item/?item_id=$1', 'top');
}

add_action( 'init', 'custom_rewrite_basic' );
```

On the `add-item` page, the variable is fetched as such:

```
$item_id = filter_input( INPUT_GET, "item_id", FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );

if(!empty($item_id)) {
    ...
```

When the page is called with `add-item/1`, `var_dump($item_id)` comes back with `NULL`. Any other number (including `0`) work fine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite rules in WordPress should point to `index.php`, and to substitute a matched value (number from address) to URL parameter (`item_id`) you must use `$matches[1]` instead of `$1`.

So your rule should look like this:

```
add_rewrite_rule('^add-item/([0-9]+)/?', 'index.php?item_id=$matches[1]', 'top');
```

You usually need to complete the rule with information about what is displayed. For display:

- *single post / page* - add to rewrite `&p={post_id}` or `&postname={post_slug}`
- *archive page* - `&post_type={post_type_slug}`
- *custom category* - `&{taxonomy_slug}={term_slug}`.

This rule setting only the `item_id` query var, so if you have not added your own function to `template_include` filter hook, WP will display the homepage.

### Edit:

**Rules with and without `index.php`**
Rewrite rules begining with `index.php` are stored in DB. When parsing request, WordPress get them from the DB and tries to match the request URL to one of the rules.

Rules that do not start with an `index.php`, do not go to the database. They are not checked when the request is being parsed by WordPress.
It is possible that they will be saved in `.htaccess` file, **but only** if you use Apache and file permissions allow for writing.

**Why *$item_id* is NULL**
`example.com/add-item/1` address is recognized as a post (post type can be `page` or `post`) with several pages (post pagination). You should know that WordPress **removes page number** from URL **if it equal to "1"**.
WordPress checks whether the requested url is canonical by comparing the url with the one it generates.
Canonical URL in this case (first page of post) is `example.com/add-item/` and it is not the same as the requested one `example.com/add-item/1`, so redirecting will be done.

I do not know what type of post is the `add-item` (custom post type or built in), but try this way:

```
add_action( 'init', 'se336565_custom_rewrite_basic' );
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'se336565_add_custom_query_var' );

function se336565_add_custom_query_var( $vars ){
  $vars[] = "item_id";
  return $vars;
}
function se336565_custom_rewrite_basic() 
{
    add_rewrite_rule('^add-item(?:/([0-9]+))/?$', 
        'index.php?post_type={custom_post_type_slug}&pagename=add-item&name=add-item&item_id=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
```

Replace `{custom_post_type_slug}` and flush the rewrite rules.

Finally, on the actual page use `get_query_var( 'item_id' )`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the reason to use `index.php`. Is there some documentation around this?

Comment: Also see my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55671643/679449) on using `$matches[1]` vs `$1`

Comment: @Kermit I've edited the answer

Comment: @Kermit I forgot to mention that in order to get variable `item_id` set by the rewrite rule, use [get_query_var](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var) function: `$item_id = get_query_var( 'item_id', false );`

Comment: @nmr is correct. `example.com/add-item/1` is considered having the same content as the page on `example.com/add-item/`, so WordPress applies canonical redirect to avoid duplicate content penalty by search engines. `example.com/add-item/2`, on the other hand, is assumed having a different content than the first page (`example.com/add-item/1`), so WordPress doesn't apply the canonical redirect - hence you "stay" on the same URL. Try `remove_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical' );` in your theme `functions.php` file, and you'd see that your `$item_id` works fine on `add-item/1`.

Comment: @SallyCJ I'm really not clear when I should be using `index.php` vs. a custom page with a custom template. Reading the *Using rewrite rules to redirect to scripts other than index.php* section in the [doc](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule), it seems like my approach is fine. Is this not best practice?

Comment: @Kermit, sorry for the late reply. Your approach is fine, but the RegEx pattern conflicts with the one WordPress have by default for paginated multi-page post/page requests. So if `add-item` is a WordPress Page (post type `page`), then you should use the `index.php` redirect (i.e. use `index.php?pagename=add-item&item_id=$matches[1]`). That way, `add-item/1` wouldn't redirect to `add-item/` (i.e. without the page number). But honestly, @nmr already answered the original question. :)

Comment: @SallyCJ @nmr `index.php?pagename=add-item&item_id=$matches[1]` redirects to `/add-item` and loses the var. When I use `index.php?page_id=216&item_id=$matches[1]` it keeps the var, but not passed into the page. The only redirect rule that works right now is `add-item/?item_id=$1`... any thoughts?

Comment: @Kermit, `add_rewrite_rule( '^add-item/([0-9]+)/?', 'index.php?pagename=add-item&item_id=$matches[1]', 'top' )` works fine for me. And to get the `item_id` value, you should use `get_query_var( 'item_id' )` and not `$_GET['item_id']` when redirecting to `index.php`.

Comment: @SallyCJ that was really helpful -- thank you. Last question; what is the difference between `get_query_var( 'item_id' )` and `filter_input( INPUT_GET, "item_id", FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT )`

Comment: @Kermit `filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'item_id' )` get variable from "superglobal" array of URL parameters (passed after `?` mark), but there are no parameters in address like `/add-item/{some_number_here}`, so `$_GET` array is empty. 
Wordpress is looking for the first rewrite rule that matching the requested URL, and **sets variables in the global `$wp_query` object** according to this rule (in you case `item_id=$matches[1]`). To get variable from `$wp_query` object, the `get_query_var()` function is used.